# jqgrid inline editing: dynamically set column editable properly of another column

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid

When I change the value of a particular column during inline edit, I want to change the editable property value of another column of the same row dynamically. Below is a part of my code:

```
{ name: "admin", width:250, editable:<?php echo $owner; ?>, edittype:"custom", editoptions: {
            custom_element: myelem,
            custom_value:myvalue,
            dataEvents: [{
                    type: 'change',
                    fn: function (e) {
                        var $this = $(e.target), $td, rowid;
                        var radSel = $(e.target).val(); //alert(radSel);
                        if(radSel == "No"){
                            if ($this.hasClass("FormElement")) {
                                $("#request").prop("editable", true);
                            } else {
                                //alert("you are here!!");
                                var row = $this.closest('tr.jqgrow');
                                var rowId = row.attr('id'); //alert(rowId);
                                $("#" + rowId + '_request').prop("editable", true);
                            }
                        }
                     }
            }]

    }},
{ name: "request", width: 100},
......

function myelem (value, options) {
var radio1 = document.createElement('input');
radio1.id = 'radY';
radio1.type = 'radio';
radio1.name = 'appr';
radio1.value = 'Yes';
if(value.match(/^Yes.*/)){ radio1.checked = true; }

var radio2 = document.createElement('input');
radio2.id = 'radN';
radio2.type = 'radio';
radio2.name = 'appr';
radio2.value = 'No';
if(value.match(/^No.*/)){ radio2.checked = true; }

var label1 = document.createElement('label');
label1.setAttribute('for', radio1.id);
label1.innerHTML = 'Yes';

var label2 = document.createElement('label');
label2.setAttribute('for', radio2.id);
label2.innerHTML = 'No';

var container = document.createElement('div');
container.appendChild(radio1);
container.appendChild(label1);
container.appendChild(radio2);
container.appendChild(label2);

return container;
}

function myvalue(elem, operation, value) {
    if(document.getElementById('radY').checked) {return "Yes";}
    else if(document.getElementById('radN').checked) {return "No";}
    else {return ""; }
}
```

When i change the radio button to "No", it *does* enter into the if loop (under dataEvents) but the editable property on the 'request' column is not set to true dynamically. Any help much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: `editable` property will be used by jqGrid *before* starting editing. **If you want to prevent editing dynamically you have to set `disable` or `reabonly` property/attribute** on the corresponding existing editing field instead of setting `editable` property. Moreover you seems to assign fix `id` attributes (`'radN'`, `'radY'`) for custom editing field. It's dangerous because you can have id duplicates. Inline editing allows you to editing more as one row at the same time. In the case two custom editing elements with the same ids will be created and you will have problems.

Comment: Moreover I recommend you to set `<input>` **inside of** `<label>`. In the case you will don't need any `id` or `for`. Try `<label><input type="radio" name="appr" checked="checked" value="Yes"/>Yes</label>&nbsp;<label><input type="radio" name="appr" value="No"/>No</label>`. One can check the radio button by clicking on the label.

Comment: I just reversed the logic and using the disable property.. thanks again for your help

Comment: I also tried removing the `id` attribute for `radio type` .. but then, i faced some challenges - how do i fetch the value of what I selected in the `myvalue` function? Right now i fetch the selected value using `document.getElementById`

Comment: Try `$(elem).find(">input[name=appr]:checked").val()` or just `$(elem).find("input:checked").val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `editable` property will be used by jqGrid *before* starting editing. **If you want to prevent editing dynamically you have to set disable or `readonly` property/attribute** on the corresponding existing editing field instead of setting `editable` property.

Moreover you seems to assign fix `id` attributes (`'radN'`, `'radY'`) for custom editing field. It's dangerous because you can have `id` duplicates. Inline editing allows you to editing more as one row at the same time. In the case two custom editing elements with the same ids will be created and you will have problems. I recommend you additionally to set `<input>` inside of `<label>`. In the case you will don't need any `id` or `for` attributes. Try

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="appr" checked="checked" value="Yes"/>Yes</label>
&nbsp;
<label><input type="radio" name="appr" value="No"/>No</label>
```

One can check the radio button by clicking on the label.

Comment: I do not want the page to do a postback if `$(elem).find("input[name=appr]:checked").val()` is empty on `enter`. But it does do a postback. I have also tried explicitly mentioning `return false` .. but it still posts an empty value back. How do i hang in there without posting ?

Comment: @MattO: Sorry, but what "posting" you mean. If required you can use `editrules` to **validate** the results. I don't understand exactly your requirements and what you do at the end. You use custom editing control in come column. Do you use it in editing or in Edit/Add form? Do you consider to specify `defaultValue` in `editoptions` for Add form or for input other as `Yes`/`No`? If you use `defaultValue` you will create radio button with always one selected value. Moreover the current custom editing control is not full. You need implement `"set"` and `"get"` operation in `myvalue` function.

Comment: hi @Oleg, sorry the delayed response. I was having issues with my internet. I actual figured out what i was looking for. By post i meant, when no option is given it shouldn't post the values to the db. I think that can be done in the edit page with an if condition and pass the response to the grid based on the values given.